# MySQL swapping columns while locking table: is my method theoretically deadlock-free?

Tags: mysql, locking, unique, deadlock

I have a friend-relation table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `FriendRelation` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_both_way` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`user_id1`, `user_id2`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The friend relations are like Twitter where one can follow another user in a one-way fashion. Only when both users follow each other they can exchange private messages. It is intended that millions of rows are to be inserted.

In my intended usage when Alice follows Bob a row will be inserted with `user_id1=Alice's Id`, `user_id2=Bob's Id`, and `is_both_way=0`. When Bob follows back the `is_both_way` flag is set to 1.

Now if Alice unfollows Bob I am thinking of SWAPPING the `user_id1` and `user_id2` while changing the `is_both_way` flag back to 0.

Basically I have two procedure psudocodes

```
function follow(self, target) {
    begin transaction;
    if ("select * from FriendRelation where user_id1=self and user_id2=target" is not empty) {
         do nothing;
    } elseif ("select * from FriendRelation where user_id1=target and user_id2=self for update" is not empty) {
         "update FriendRelation set is_both_way=1 where user_id1=target and user_id2=self";
    } else {
         "insert into FriendRelation (user_id1, user_id2, is_both_way) values (self, target, 0)";
    }
    commit;
}

function unfollow(self, target) {
    begin transaction;
    if ("select * from FriendRelation where user_id1=self and user_id2=target for update" is not empty) {
         "update FriendRelation set is_both_way=0, user_id1=target, user_id2=self where user_id1=self and user_id2=target";
    } elseif ("select * from FriendRelation where user_id1=target and user_id2=self for update" is not empty) {
         "delete from FriendRelation where user_id1=target and user_id2=self";
    }
    commit;
}
```

However I am not sure whether this way can cause deadlocks and/or unintended bugs to happen as I am locking the records for every update operation and the table has a unique constraint. I have thought for a while but couldn't think of a case where this does not work but just have a gut feeling that this way might cause some problems.

If this is indeed unsafe I would resort to using two separate records for the two direction of following which is trivially safe but takes two times storage.

Comment: Make your `is_both_way` bit-mapped. If A follows B then the flag is 1. When B follows back the flag is set to 3. If then A unfollows B then the flag is set to 2. To simplify this you may use `SET('user 1 only','user 2 only','both users')` datatype.. I'd also think about undirected structure: `(user_id, following_id, approve)`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a no-risk method indeed.

Comment: Actually I thought for a while there might be a potential problem: when two people simultaneously follow each other there might be a possibility that two records with different flag and user_ids in different order existing in the database, which is unintended.

Comment: In the swapped-order way of handlling this problem might also exists...maybe I have to resort to two records for each direction way to be bug-free

Comment: *when two people simultaneously follow each other there might be a possibility that two records with different flag and user_ids in different order existing in the database, which is unintended.* No such problem - you'd simply create unique index by an expression `(LEAST(user1, user2), GREATEST(user1, user2))`. And maybe CHECK constraint by `(user1<>user2)`.

Comment: Yes I think that should work. BTW I have never used the LEAST, GREATEST keys before, will the overhead (in terms of both storage and processing) more significant than normal composite keys or just about the same?

Comment: This is common composite key. The values are calculated during data insert/update only, so you may detect the execution rate difference only in huge batch data changes.